# Change remote target in VS 2015 w/ GDB extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

I am using VS2015 for developing small projects for my RasPi. But now I want to change the target machine from raspberry pi to another Linux PC (x64).

How can I change the target? I tried using Project-Properties->Remote Settings->Target but it has no effect. It still tries to connect to the first RasPi.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ok I found out, that you have to add a new remote machine:
Extras->Options->Cross Compiling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS 2017: Tools->Options->Cross Platform->Connection Manager (remove record(s) from table and restart project)